# How do I correctly initialize wide character string?

Tags: c++, c, string, char

I am trying to figure out wide characters in c. For example, I test a string that contains a single letter "Ē" that is encoded as c492 in utf8.

```
char* T1 = "Ē";
//This is the resulting array { 0xc4, 0x92, 0x00 }

wchar_t* T2 = L"Ē";
//This is the resulting array { 0x00c4, 0x2019, 0x0000 }
```

I expected that the second array would be {0xc492, 0x0000}, instead it contains an extra character that just wastes space in my opinion. Can anyone help me understand what is going on with this?

Comment: Which encoding is used to save the source file?

Comment: If anything, I'd expect the second array to be {0x0112, 0x0000}, which is the utf-16 or utf-32 encoding. I have no idea what encoding { 0x00c4, 0x2019, 0x0000 } is supposed to be in.

Comment: Character 0xC492 looks like this [쒒](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/c492/index.htm)

Comment: Also, note that string literals are arrays of `const` characters. Your code is using a deprecated conversion from string literal to pointer to character. This used to work only for reasons of backwards compatibility with C and was removed in C++11. Don't do this. The content of a string literal *must not* be modified. Make your pointers point to `const` characters…

Comment: Also, the fact that this would even compile suggests that you must be using an ancient compiler. You may wanna consider upgrading…

Comment: ... or they are using a C compiler, @MichaelKenzel.  The OP having tagged both C and C++, it is unclear which language they are actually using.

Comment: @JohnBollinger true, I overlooked that, thanks for pointing that out. Even in C, however, one should be using pointers to `const` in this case, despite the fact that it would also compile without `const`…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your compiler is misinterpreting your source code file (which is saved as UTF-8) as Windows-1252 (commonly called ANSI). It does not interpret the byte sequence `C4 92` as the one-character UTF-8 string "Ē", but as the two-character Windows-1252 string `"Ä’"`. The unicode codepoint of `"Ä"` is U+00C4, and the unicode codepoint of `"’"` is U+2019. This is exactly what you see in your wide character string.

The 8-bit string only works, because the misinterpretation of the string does not matter, as it is not converted during compilation. The compiler reads the string as Windows-1252 and emits the string as Windows-1252 (so it does not need to convert anything, and considers both to be "Ä’"). You interpret the source code and the data in the binary as UTF-8, so you consider both to be `"Ē"`.

To have the compiler treat your source code as UTF-8, use the switch [/utf-8](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/build/reference/utf-8-set-source-and-executable-character-sets-to-utf-8?view=vs-2019).

BTW: The correct UTF-16 encoding (which is the encoding MSVC uses for wide character strings) to be observed in a wide-character string is *not* `{0xc492, 0x0000}`, but `{0x0112, 0x0000}`, because `"Ē"` is `U+0112`.

Answer (score 5):

What you've managed to do here is mojibake. Your source code is written in UTF-8 but it was **interpreted in Windows codepage 1252** (i.e. the compiler *source character set was CP1252*).

The wide string contents are the **Windows codepage 1252** characters of the UTF-8 bytes 0xC4 0x92 converted to UCS-2. The **easiest way out** is to just using an escape instead:

```
wchar_t* T2 = L"\x112";
```

or

```
wchar_t* T2 = L"\u0112";
```

---

The larger problem is that to my knowledge neither C nor C++ have a mechanism for specifying the source character set within the code itself, so it is always a setting or option external to something that you can easily copy-paste.

Comment: The easier way out is to save the file as **UTF-8 with BOM** and not muck with hexadecimal escapes.

Comment: @n.m. The easiest way out to ensure that the code doesn't work anywhere...

Comment: Please find an implementation where this doesn't work by default.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala not anywhere except in MSVC. It is documented behaviour of MSVC to detect UTF-8 encoded source files by the presence of the BOM. Still you are right that this is not conformant to the UTF-8 standard (which does not allow to ignore the U+FEFF character (BOM) at beginning of the file) in conjunction with ANSI C (which defines U+FEFF at the beginning of the file to be a syntax error).

Comment: Well on my computer only TCC failed to compile it. Except that the BOM didn't have any effect in either direction because my locale is set to UTF-8

Comment: @n.m. ok so you're incorrect. The BOM is *ignored* by Clang and GCC, not ignored by TCC, where it causes a syntax error. I.e. it is *only* MSVC where this has any effect. GCC and Clang use UTF-8 as the source character set unless hinted otherwise by the locale, in which case they ignore the BOM.

Comment: Well you may need to babysit niche compilers I guess.

Comment: @MichaelKarcher "which defines U+FEFF at the beginning of the file to be a syntax error" Can you show relevant wording in the standard?

Comment: @n.m. there is none. It is all "implementation-specified" which was my point.

Comment: Actually, @n.m., there is.  Section 5.2.1 defines the requirements for source and execution character sets, and the end of [paragraph 5.2.1/3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.1p3) specifies that "If any other characters are encountered in a source file (except in an identifier, a character constant, a string literal, a header name, a comment, or a preprocessing token that is never converted to a token), the behavior is undefined."  It is hard (but perhaps not impossible) to interpret a BOM as not being "any other character".

Comment: @JohnBollinger 5.1.1.2 says that "Physical source file multibyte characters are mapped, in an implementation- defined manner, to the source character set (introducing new-line characters for end-of-line indicators) if necessary." - an implementation can specify to delete the BOM. In any case it cannot *remain* in the actual code.

Comment: *The BOM is ignored by Clang and GCC* So it has the desired effect. *not ignored by TCC, where it causes a syntax error* UTF-8 files are allowed to contain BOM by the Unicode standard. "" If TCC claims to support Unicode source files, then it is probably a bug. *unless hinted otherwise by the locale, in which case they ignore the BOM* I'm not sure this is entirely correct, but if it is, then they do not interpret the source as UTF-8, which is fine, they may do with it as they please.

Comment: Ok, yes, @AnttiHaapala.  In practice, however, at least GCC *does not* define that it performs any such trick, so either its documentation is buggy / non-conforming, or its implementation is.

Comment: @JohnBollinger "The mapping between physical source file multibyte characters and the source character set in translation phase" is implementation defined. Mapping the physical BOM to empty source character string is a very reasonable implementation choice.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala The C standard does not specify any mapping between byte sequences in the source file and the basic source character set. So it is definitely legal for a C compiler to remove the BOM at the beginning of a source code file as part of reading the source file. But if the mapping from bytes to characters produces a BOM, it is "any other character". Still, ignoring the BOM is a valid, but not mandatory behaviour of a C compiler. I was wrong with the claim that you must not strip the BOM in UTF8. Section 6 of RFC3629 explicitly says otherwise (3rd paragraph).

Comment: So my conclusion that referencing the UTF-8 standard as the way how to map source file bytes to source file characters mandates keeping the BOM was wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately GCC docs are rather vague on the behaviour - the only text is "The input character set can be specified using the -finput-charset option, while the execution character set may be controlled using the -fexec-charset and -fwide-exec-charset options.". But in any case, if the claim was that using BOM makes the compiler know that the file is written in UTF-8 has been proved wrong anyway.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala No, using BOM does not make *any* compiler know. I have never said that. It's all too easy to prove it wrong. BOM makes MSVC know, and gcc simply doesn't need it by default (clang probably too). The standard does not mandate implementations to switch to UTF-8 upon seeing the BOM, and I have never said that either. The standard allows BOM in UTF-8 files, that's all I have said.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala gcc docs are rather vague in many places, this one included. However there is a bugzilla entry that talks about allowing BOM in source files. It was fixed back in 2008.